# The good way to control several threads

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading

I have a MDI WinForms application that can perform several tasks. Each task is running as a backgroundWorker.

What is the good approach to control the running threads:

- check whether the specific thread is running
- stop specific thread ?

For example it shouldn't be possible to run the same task simultaneously.

May be I need a separate class where I can store isTaskRunning variable?

How is the good way to do this?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you could take would be to create a class per task.  Then let that class perform the tasks.  It will know if multiple tasks could be used at once, and restrict access to each of them. Hence :

```
public class LongUploadTask
{
  private bool isRunning;


  public void Execute()
  {
    if(!isRunning)
    {
       //etc...
    }
  }
}
```

Note, I have left out locking code if you are accessing this from multiple threads, which I don't think you are.  In addition, if you wanted to execute this asyncronously, you could use asynchronous delegates and manual reset events to achieve what your BackgroundWorker's are doing.

Comment: this is how i would do it as well :)